# R group_by and filter with multiple conditions

Tags: r, filter, group-by

I have a dataset like the following:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
LABEL <- c('TT', 'CH', 'AB', 'TT', 'CH', 'AB', 'TT', 'CH', 'TT', 'CH', 'AB')
VALUE <- c(2121, 32, 1, 2121, 32, 2, 2121, 99, 2222, 32, 9)

DATA <- data.frame(ID, LABEL, VALUE)
```

I'm trying to group the data by ID (it's a long file where ID replicates) then filter where the same ID meets multiple conditions.  I've tried the following:

```
X <- DATA %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter( 
    (LABEL == "TT" & VALUE == "2121") & 
      (LABEL == "CH" & VALUE == "32") )
```

I want to get a dataset with only the observations with ID 1 and 2 which meet both conditions simultaneously.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `any` - after grouping by 'ID', if we want to check for presence of the strings in two columns, wrap with `any` as multiple expression cannot be TRUE for the same location.  Then, we use `&` so that if only both are present it returns `TRUE` (`any` - returns a single TRUE/FALSE)

```
library(dplyr)
DATA %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter( 
    any((LABEL == "TT" & VALUE == "2121") &
      any((LABEL == "CH" & VALUE == "32") ))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ID LABEL VALUE
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 TT     2121
2     1 CH       32
3     1 AB        1
4     2 TT     2121
5     2 CH       32
6     2 AB        2
```

---

Or slighly more compact option by `paste`ing the columns and then check if `all` the elements in the lhs of `%in%` are TRUE for `filter`ing the groups

```
library(stringr)
DATA %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(all(c("TT2121", "CH32") %in% str_c(LABEL, VALUE))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ID LABEL VALUE
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 TT     2121
2     1 CH       32
3     1 AB        1
4     2 TT     2121
5     2 CH       32
6     2 AB        2
```